# dhtmlx scheduler for recurring events

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler, recurring-events

I am trying to add recurring events in calendar using dhtmlx scheduler.

```
var data = {
                start_date: "2017-12-03 10:00:00",
                end_date: "2019-12-22 10:00:00",
                text: "test",
                rec_type: "week_1___6",
                event_length: 720
            };
        scheduler.parse(data, 'json');
```

I have but the event is not adding in the calendar. I even tried scheduler.addEvent that also did not work.

Can you please let me know where I am making a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You should add square brackets

`var data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      start_date: "2017-12-03 10:00:00", 
      end_date: "2019-12-22 10:00:00",
      text:"test",
      rec_type: "week_1___6",
      event_pid: "0",
      event_length: 60*60*2
    }
];`

After that recurring events will be displayed to Scheduler:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/snippet/d3b3adaa